# Visualforce Email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I'm trying to create vf email template.I 'm getting the below error

Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.Opportunity'

for opportunity-Product and OSF Order Iems are related lists.

work around:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="NA US Credit Check Notification" 
                         recipientType="User" 
                         relatedToType="Opportunity">

    <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

    Hi COS team, 

    I have just Closed/Won the opportunity `{!Opportunity.Name}` related to the account `{!Opportunity.Account}`. 

    [Product2ID] - [BigMachines Part Number] - [Hyperion Code] - [OSF Order Item - Part Number]

    <apex:repeat var="cx"  value="{!relatedTo.Product2}">
        [{!cx.Id}] - [{!cx.BigMachines__Part_Number__c}] - [{!cx.Hyperion_Code__c} ] ]
    </apex:repeat>

    <apex:repeat var="xx"  value="{!relatedTo.OSF_Order_Items__c}">
        [{xx.Part_Number__c}]
    </apex:repeat>

    Please follow this link to access the Order Summary Form information: {!Opportunity.Link} 


    </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your relatedTo object is the Opportunity, so you should be referencing it as {!relatedTo.field}, not {!Opportunity.field}.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance I would have thought you'd need to access the OpportunityLineItems and OSF_Order_Items__r in your repeat blocks.

e.g.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="NA US Credit Check Notification" 
                         recipientType="User" 
                         relatedToType="Opportunity">

    <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

    Hi COS team, 

    I have just Closed/Won the opportunity `{!Opportunity.Name}` related to the account `{!Opportunity.Account}`. 

    [Product2ID] - [BigMachines Part Number] - [Hyperion Code] - [OSF Order Item - Part Number]

    <apex:repeat var="cx"  value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityLineItems}">
        [{!cx.Id}] - [{!cx.BigMachines__Part_Number__c}] - [{!cx.Hyperion_Code__c} ] ]
    </apex:repeat>

    <apex:repeat var="xx"  value="{!relatedTo.OSF_Order_Items__r}">
        [{xx.Part_Number__c}]
    </apex:repeat>

    Please follow this link to access the Order Summary Form information: {!Opportunity.Link} 


    </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.yup i changed . And what i observe is here we can't access cross object.This could be done with custom vf

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use a custom component in your email so you can use the controller behind the component to query the related data and format it for the email how you need it. Salesforce have a good example of how to build one at use it below:

[Custom Controllers in Email Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm)

Hope this helps.